# Create a file folder for app

Tags: android, android-file

The below code doesn't create a folder in my device.

```
    String intStorageDirectory = context.getFilesDir().toString();
    File folder = new File(intStorageDirectory, "test");
    folder.createNewFile();;
```

I need a folder created for my app to store media, when user installs it. That folder should be visible on file explorer. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current snippet you created a file, you can also create folder by creating file but your current directory is the base folder, getFilesDir() points [internal storage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteInternalStorage) for your app which not visible nor accessible unless explicitly declared. You can create a folder and file by creating with `new File().createNewFile()` or  create only folder using `mkdirs()` but you won't be able to display it using a file explorer app and that folder and files inside it will be deleted when/if user uninstalls your app.

To save files externally(This doesn't mean saving to SD Card) you can create directory and file with

```
File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), folderName);
if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
    mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()
}
File mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + fileName);
```

And you need some kind of `OutputStream` to write data to that file.

Make sure that you ask `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` inside your AndroidManifest.xml file and ask write permission on runtime if your  `android:targetSdkVersion="23"` or above

Comment: i want that file to be seen on file explorer. apps like whatsap, telegram have such a folder. i need the same. how can i do that then?

Comment: I edited the answer for saving to external storage but you should read and understand the `Saving Files` to understand saving files correctly. This one of the fundamental concept in programming and you should not skip learning it throughly.

Comment: can u please provide me the link for that?

Comment: Check the aswer. I added link there.

Answer (score 0):

```
new File(context.getFielsDir(), "test").mkdirs();
```

createNewFile creates a file, not a folder.  Using mkdirs instead of mkdir ensures that all parents exist.  There's also no reason to go through a string when you already have a File.

Comment: i don't know whether it really works or not. i can't see a folder in file explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Adding folder.mkdirs(); should work in place of folder.createNewFile(); And don't forget to add the permissions.

This will create a folder in you data directory.
And just a suggestion , if you want to store media in a SD card folder maybe Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() is good.

Comment: You don't need permission to save or create folder internally.

Comment: Sorry i meant if you want to store files in external  directory.

Comment: It's my mistake, i missed out the external directory part.

Comment: it doesn't make a folder which  i can see using file explorer